# How can I find out which c++ compiler is Xcode 5 using?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction

I am currently writing c++ code and compiling using Xcode. I was wondering: How can I find out which c++ compiler is Xcode 5 using?
I would like to know that to make sure that the program I am writing is compilable on other computers that don't necessarily use the same compiler.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your target's build settings to see what the current setting is. However, Xcode 5 only uses the LLVM 5.0 compiler. GCC is no longer used.

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/features.html

[image]